# Hyperlink with URL fragment (hashbang)

Tags: html

I have a website (URL: http://www.example.com/#!home) with the following hyperlink:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/#!about">About</a>
```

When I click the link, it does not redirect. Browser did nothing. How do I navigate to the `/#!about` page with `<a>` tag?

Comment: Is your site a SPA? Are you using pushState for navigation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such links need to be handled in JavaScript. In particular, you need to have JavaScript code on your page that handles the [hashchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange). I would strongly recommend emitting these links as separate server URLs (i.e. use "/about" instead of "#!/about") so that browsers with JavaScript disabled can navigate to them, and then in the code that registers the hashchange event listener, update all these URLs to point to the hash, instead (the fact that it is updated in JavaScript proves that JavaScript is enabled and can handle the links).

Answer (score 1):

Use an alphanumeric folder name.

Comment: you mean without hashbang?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Raptor.  Yes, I meant without the hashbang.

Comment: @Zefnus.  Deleting my answer was disrespectful.  It is a valid answer.  Your suggestion of leaving an answer BELOW their post is not possible for me, because I need 50 reputation points.  That is why I answered here.  I hope you use your reputation in best practices.

Comment: @mugé The description you see there is *auto* posted. It includes two links for details about reputation and commenting other user's posts. For your answer, it is *correct* but it *lacks* the details which makes it a *low quality* answer. You can improve you answer adding a reference for `alphanumeric` definition, adding demonstration such as: "Using `/about` instead of `/#!about` will solve the issue"

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  I appreciate that you came back and explained.  I have been posting here as of yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a").live("click", function(event){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if(href[0] == "/"){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.hash = "#!" + href;
    }
});
```